# How to find default download directory in linux through c program?

Tags: linux, download, ubuntu-12.04

As I titled,

is there any API available, to determine the default download directory in the Linux?

I am using ubuntu distribution.

Comment: Location can be different.It depends on application. basically it is ~/download

Comment: Is it? Well, could be ... it's up to the user, isn't it I didn't knew there are any rules for this. @rkosegi

Comment: similar answer as the as the correct one from @djasa but with a little bit more background: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/511910/93768

Answer (score 26):

Quite late to the party but: There is XDG specification that covers exactly this topic. To get the download directory in shell (script) just run:

```
$ xdg-user-dir DOWNLOAD
/home/djasa/Downloads
```

For programs, the location is available in `$HOME/.config/user-dirs.dirs`:

```
$ grep DOWNLOAD .config/user-dirs.dirs 
XDG_DOWNLOAD_DIR="$HOME/Downloads"
```

For more information about XDG, read man pages that `man -k xdg` returns to you.

Comment: The only right answer! XDG actually covers the issue. Because downloads dir can look like: `~/Downloads`, `~/downloads`, `~/Завантаження` and so on. And `$ xdg-user-dir [folder_type]` prints the actual dir name. P.S. Also every user can customize his directories by editing XDG configuration file.

Comment: Usage as a variable: `DOWNLOAD_PATH=$(xdg-user-dir DOWNLOAD)`

Comment: If `xdg-user-dir` is missing on Arch Linux install it with `sudo pacman -S xdg-user-dirs`.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best approximation is using HOME environment variable of the user. In many distros you can use then subfolders inside, but it does not apply to all distros.

Answer (score 0):

There is no "default download directory" at the level of the OS, though all current distros will create a `~/Downloads` directory for this purpose and most browsers will choose it by default.  What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Andy , to monitor the downloads, using inotify.

Comment: Right.  So `$HOME/Downloads` is your best bet.  But the user is not required to use this directory, so will not (cannot!) catch all of them.

Comment: some distros localize the downloads folder to the local language. for instance in Spanish is `Descargas`.

Comment: logoff: which distro is that?  Localizing paths in the filesystem is almost always a disaster...

Comment: This answer is wrong. See @djasa's answer regarding `xdg-user-dir`.

Answer (score 0):

There are no standards for how to organise user data on Linux, besides that in most of the cases it goes to where `$HOME` points to.

One excpetion to this is where to place and how to name files and directories to store user specific application configruations. They shall go to the root of the users home, and those file/directories shall start with a  `.`. Please [see here for this](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html#REQUIREMENTS4A).

For system files there do exist guide lines, namely the [FHS](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html).